# how can signing/encryption of token based authentication work for a stateless server (REST)

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-web-api, token, basic-authentication

I have clients which are all browsers.
All clients render just a single page application getting data from a Web API.
The design of the API follows REST principles.

This is my authentication flow:

1. I use basic authentication over SSL for my login view.
2. If the user`s sent username and password are valid I put a token string into the response
3. This token is stored in the local storage on client side
4. Each further request to a ressource endpoint of the server API includes the token.
5. Before I do further investigation with the token like checking its expiration date:
6. I need to know wether the authenticity of the token is still valid or someone has modified it. This assumes that the token was signed with a key before.

   OR
7. I need to decrypt the encrypted token.

Question 1) Do steps 6 and 7 make sense using SSL ?

Question 2) Lets assume steps 6 and 7 make sense then I would have done the following:

When the for example json web token (JWT) after successful login is created I sign it with a key. This key is somewhere on the server stored maybe in an xml file or in a singleton class.

Wherever I store this sign key when I create the token I have to use the same key to validate the token. The same is valid for the encryption of the token. How is it possible to use different sign keys for a token maybe on a user basis. That means each authenticated login gets a token with an individual sign key.

The next time the user is requesting a resource endpoint I want to know whether the token has still the authenticity. But I can check this only with the same sign key the token was created with.

Question 3) Where should this sign key be stored ?

Answer (score 4):

If you use JWT you have different possibilities of security:

1. Sign the token (see [`JWS`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature)). In this case a man-in-the-middle can still read the contents of this token but cannot modify it because he doesn't have the key to sign it and when the server checks the authenticity of the token it will detect that it has been tampered with
2. Encrypt the token (see [`JWE`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-encryption)). In this case a man-in-the middle cannot read the contents of the token, nor he can modify its contents.

Using SSL in your case would ensure that the token cannot be stolen by man-in-the-middles. So unless you have some super secret information stored inside this token, signing it should be sufficient. Obviously the signing key should be stored on the server only and not shared with the rest of the world.

As far as your question about signing the token with different keys depending on the user is concerned, I don't think this is necessary.

Personally I would use a JWT token which contains only a minimum information like the [`exp`](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#expDef) and [`jti`](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#jtiDef) claims and sign it with a secret key. Then I would use the value of this token as key in a key/value store on the server (could be some cache implementation like memcached or NoSQL DB) and would associate the username and any other necessary information to this token. The value will be cached for the duration of validity of the token. When the client sends the JWT token to the server, the server would validate the signature of the token to ensure that its value hasn't been tampered with and then look it the cache for the associated user information.

Comment: I looked in the claims types list but could not find your "jti" = JWT ID ? You have a direct link? See further information at Badri`s comment. So you would store the general signing key in the database ? Just in which table... What about storing the key a xml file/app.config/web.config?

Comment: Here's a link for the jti claim: http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#jtiDef Its purpose is to provide uniqueness of the access tokens. As far as storing the signing key is concerned, you could use your web.config. I wouldn't store it in a database.

Comment: Seems so many people do it differently. Maybe each one wants a different level of security? I do not know. Badri advises me to rotate the keys. How can I do that dynamically when the key is inside the web.config? Alternative is using ONE signing key for all tokens secure? My colleague just said a signing key per user is nonsense and thats defeating the purpose of an auth token going to the database... So many opinions...

Comment: Elisa... just to be clear, I suggested storing the key in web.config and the key to be changed on a periodic basis, say every month. I don't think you will need to have the complexity of having a key associated with a month, user, etc. If a token is issued just before you change the key, the request with old token will fail. So what? Authentication can be retried to get a token signed with new key. I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: @Badri "So what? Authentication can be retried to get a token signed with new key. I don't understand what your problem is." My problem is that while the user is fetching data he gets a 401 and is redirected to my login view. Following your suggestion the user will one time in a month see the login view because the token validation failed. The user will think the application is buggy. This is my problem. And sorry if I said something which you did not mean. Then it was just a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

SSL prevents tampering by men in the middle but what about the end users themselves? I don't trust anybody including end users. Any evil end user can hijack the token from a common machine or some one else's and simply send the token back to the server. If that is okay to you in terms of the security requirements you have, SSL is good enough.

However, people use the term **token** to indicate any kind of blob. But a software security token is supposed to be the container of claims. If you do indeed use your token to store claims, it is very important to check the integrity by validating the signature. Even a legit user can add bogus claims and push the token over to the server through HTTPS.

You can have a key per user. You can store it where ever you want it. But you need to ensure the security of the keys.

Comment: In my situation my token has exactly one claim which is the nameidentifier which is the userId. For every ressource request I use the userId in the principal to check wether the current user is ressource owner of the current request like userId 1 can delete Ressource belonging to userId 1. Signing the token is fine for me because there is nothing secret about an userId. I just want to make sure that a legit user does not modify the readable json token with another userId. All that is known by me and was not my final question.

Comment: Now I need to know - have not found any info nowhere- how do I store the signing key (not a key per user just ONE key) at best following a stateless server (REST).

Comment: If it is ONE key, you can store it in web.config. Make sure you rotate the key at regular intervals.

Comment: "rotate the key". A very noobish suggestion would be 12 keys in the web.config with an assigned month value. When a new token is created I check the current month and get by this month the key from the web.config. When I validate the token via ValidateToken(tokenString, validationParameters); I check the month in the token when the token was issued so I can get the right key from the web.config because a different key would not work. You think that approach is ok from security aspect?

Comment: Just have one key and have it changed at a frequency of your choice. Tokens are typically short-lived, an hour or two may be. A token that lives for months is not typical.

Comment: "frequency of your choice". Which timespan for the validity of a signed key would be insecure? Now we move away from the static storing of the key in the web.config to something more dynamic in-memory => "Tokens are typically short-lived, an hour or 2 maybe..." When I create a token for user1 with key1 later I create a token for user2 with key2. Now I validate token for user1 with new key2. That will fail. That means imho that every token needs a key_id pointing to a dictionary<key_id,key> to get the right key for validation. How is that possible in a stateless server (REST).

Comment: I was browsing security stackexchange a bit and found way more useful information. I think that forum would have been a better place to ask ;-) Link that helped me: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19676/token-based-authentication-securing-the-token I will still summarize my approach the next days in my init question but before I have to suggest my new approach on the above forum :)